# CRS conversion using Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area project goes wrong for LAEA EUROPE using C#

Tags: coordinate-system, dotspatial

When I try convert Lat Long from shapefile using Dotspatial for Europe LAEA and it gives null values for whole Europe region. It is a custom CRS provided by client

I have used Dotspatial and tried conversion based on given PROJCS and I have tried for Russia, North and South America  CRS and it works fine except Europe.

Below is the custom CRS provided by client

> PROJCS["WGS84LAEAEurope_54386_PCRS",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["FALSE_EASTING",4321000.0],PARAMETER["FALSE_NORTHING",3210000.0],PARAMETER["CENTRAL_MERIDIAN",9.999999999999989],PARAMETER["LATITUDE_OF_ORIGIN",52.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0],AUTHORITY["XXX",722486]]

It provided NaN for complete Europe region, like UK , Spain, Italy, France etc.,

Below are Lt and Long information which I try to convert

Lat= 57.04632319800004 Long =6.977629678000028
Lat= 57.04357274600005 Long =6.945070506000036
Lat= 57.04062228300006 Long =6.912269669000068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used OSGeo.MapGuide to convert LAT/LONG to X, Y for Europe LAEA.

Below is the code which is used for CRS conversion

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MENTOR_DICTIONARY_PATH", @"D:\cs-map-dictionaries.3.1.1.9378\dictionaries", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
csFactory = new MgCoordinateSystemFactory();
//Create WGS84 coord sys
wgs84 = csFactory.CreateFromCode("LL84");
//Create UTM coord sys
utm = csFactory.CreateFromCode("ETRF89.Europe/EqArea");
xform = csFactory.GetTransform(wgs84, utm);
MgCoordinate transformed = xform.Transform(x, y);
//MgCoordinate contains your transformed coordinates
tx = transformed.GetX();
ty = transformed.GetY();
```

Comment: Hope this is clear.